# Ошибка 0xc0000135 в QT после переноса проекта

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Перенес проект на QT с компьютера с Windows 7 32-bit на ноутбук Windows 10 64-bit. На ноутбуки тот же компилятор, который был на компьютере (Qt_5_9_1_MinGW_32bit).

Использую следующие библиотеки: SOIL, opengl32, GLFW3, freetype, gdi32, irr-Klang, ikpMP3. Версии библиотек и прилегающих хедеров те же, что были на ПК. Бибиотека Soil была скомпилирована на ПК и перенесена на ноут (на ноуте скомпилировать не получилось).

Мой .pro файл

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

QT += opengl

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/'../Simple OpenGL Image Library/lib/' -lSOIL

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/'../Simple OpenGL Image Library'
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/'../Simple OpenGL Image Library'

LIBS += -lopengl32

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    settings/class/game.cpp \
    settings/class/shader.cpp \
    settings/class/texture.cpp \
    settings/class/resource_manager.cpp \
    settings/class/sprite_renderer.cpp \
    settings/class/cube_render.cpp \
    settings/class/camera.cpp \
    settings/class/game_object.cpp \
    settings/class/pickingtexture.cpp \
    settings/class/effects.cpp \
    settings/class/post_processor.cpp \
    settings/class/text_renderer.cpp \
    settings/class/cube_map.cpp \
    settings/class/cube_arr_render.cpp \
    settings/class/labar/labar.cpp \
    settings/class/labar/mesh.cpp \
    settings/class/labar/model.cpp

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../GLFW/lib-mingw/ -lglfw3

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../GLFW/lib-mingw
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../GLFW/lib-mingw

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../GLFW/lib-mingw/ -lglfw3dll

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../GLFW/lib-mingw
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../GLFW/lib-mingw

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../GLFW/include/GLFW/


win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../GnuWin32/lib/ -llibfreetype.dll

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../GnuWin32/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../GnuWin32/include

HEADERS += \
    ../GLFW/include/GLFW/glfw3.h \
    ../GLFW/include/GLFW/glfw3native.h \
    settings/class/game.h \
    settings/class/shader.h \
    settings/class/texture.h \
    settings/class/resource_manager.h \
    settings/class/sprite_renderer.h \
    settings/class/cube_render.h \
    settings/class/camera.h \
    settings/class/game_object.h \
    settings/class/pickingtexture.h \
    settings/class/effects.h \
    settings/class/post_processor.h \
    settings/class/camera0.h \
    settings/class/text_renderer.h \
    settings/class/cube_map.h \
    settings/class/cube_arr_render.h \
    settings/class/labar/labar.h \
    settings/class/labar/mesh.h \
    settings/class/labar/model.h



win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/ -lgdi32

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../GnuWin32/lib/ -lfreetype

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../GnuWin32/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../GnuWin32/include

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../irrKlang-1.5.0/lib/Win32-gcc/ -lirrKlang

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../irrKlang-1.5.0/lib/Win32-gcc
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../irrKlang-1.5.0/lib/Win32-gcc

win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../irrKlang-1.5.0/lib/Win32-gcc/irrKlang.lib
else:win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../irrKlang-1.5.0/lib/Win32-gcc/libirrKlang.a

LIBS += -L$$PWD/../irrKlang-1.5.0/bin/win32-gcc/ -likpMP3
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../irrKlang-1.5.0/include

LIBS += -L$$PWD/../irrKlang-1.5.0/bin/win32-gcc/ -lirrKlang
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../irrKlang-1.5.0/include

DISTFILES += \
    settings/shaders/quad.frag \
    settings/shaders/sprite.frag \
    settings/shaders/check.frag \
    settings/shaders/screen.frag \
    settings/shaders/cube_tex_2d.frag \
    settings/shaders/cube_tex_3D_arr.frag \
    settings/text_files/T_fs.txt \
    settings/text_files/T_vs.txt \
    settings/skybox/sky_box.frag \
    settings/shaders/Cube_arr_sh/cube_arr.frag \
    settings/shaders/check.vert \
    settings/shaders/cube_tex_2d.vert \
    settings/shaders/cube_tex_3D_arr.vert \
    settings/shaders/quad.vert \
    settings/shaders/screen.vert \
    settings/shaders/sprite.vert \
    settings/shaders/Cube_arr_sh/cube_arr.vert \
    settings/shaders/Cube_arr_sh/cube_arr.gm \
    settings/skybox/sky_box.vert \
    settings/shaders/labarSh/labarsh.frag \
    settings/shaders/labarSh/labarsh.vert
```

Запускается пустая консоль и выдается ошибка:

> During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.

Возможно, это из-за 64-битной разрядности операционной системы, я не знаю.

Comment: __Бибиотека Soil была скомпилирована на ПК и перенесена на ноут__ - в этом и проблема, все библиотеки надо пересобрать на 64 бит версии.

Comment: Даже если я компилирую на mingw32?

Comment: Код другого формата на выходе

Comment: какого другого формата? Похоже кто-то тянет .NET и что-то из него не хватает. Есть такая программка depends, анализирует что из dll нужно, ей тоже можно попробовать посмотреть

Answer (score 0):

Обычно ошибка 135 связанно с тем что вы не указали путь к bin в переменных средах свойств компьютера. Попробуйте указать потом перезапустить IDE.